AutoScaling group has wrong tag value using Terraform EKS module
We are using the Terraform EKS module with managed node groups, a custom launch template (created within the node group), and in this case, the group is creating spot instances.
The node group contains this block:
tags = {
  "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled" = "false"
}

Everywhere up to the AWS created autoscaling group looks correct but the ASG shows it as true regardless of what i do.
These resources show tags/resource tags with the correct value and where applicable "Tag Instances" is true:

Custom launch template created within the node group module (my-launch-template)
EKS created launch template (eks-XXX)

How can I propagate the tag to the ASG so that it has that tag set in the node group (our autoscaler in K8S is set to exclude any nodes with that label)?
